# Speed Up Podcasts on iPod Classic

Tags: itunes, ipod, podcasts, audio

I'm looking for a way to listen to podcasts at 2x on my iPod classic. I know this is not supported out of the box.

Is there an alternative firmware like rockbox, that supports syncing with iTunes and double playback speed or - which I assume is likelier - a Mac app that allows me to easily speed up the mp3 files. With easily I mean it should support editing in batch and replacing the files automatically, ideally started with a script directly in iTunes.

(I do know about audacity, but I want something a little more automated)

Answer (score 1):

There's no such way to do that, actually. So, you have two possibilities:

1. Adjust the tempo before add the podcast on your phone (using Audacity or something similar), you can have a look on [this Super User post](https://superuser.com/questions/81045/podcast-playback-faster-than-1x-speed-on-ipod) to understand how to do it.
2. Convert the podcast into an audiobook format. You can adjust the actual velocity of your audiobook going into "Settings > Audiobooks"

Besides that, I can't see no other way to do that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Set the media Kind to Audiobook in iTunes and re-sync.